# Where should I initialize a variable to work in an IF block?

Tags: java, variables, if-statement, initialization

I'm trying to solve this problem on CodingBat:

> Return true if the given string contains between 1 and 3 'e' chars.

So far, I have this solution, but it won't compile if I have the "numofe" integer initialized inside the IF block, because other parts of the code won't work with it, and vice versa. So where should I initialize a variable, to be accessible everywhere in the code?

Thank you.

```
public boolean stringE(String str) {

  int numofe;

  for(int x = 0; str.length() > x; x++){

    if (str.charAt(x)=='e'){

      numofe++;
    }

  }
   return (numofe>0 && numofe<4);
}
```

Comment: Change `int numofe;` to `int numofe = 0;` - The compiler has detected that it's possible for the local variable to never be initialised, so it can make a valid determination about it's state

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variables within a block should be initialized before you use them, initialize them with an initial value , it could be any allowed value. but you can not use them without first initialize them.

```
int numofe=0;
```

This will not compile `numofe++;`, because `numofe` is not initialized in your code

Comment: Thank you! Solved it. (what a noob question)

Answer (score 0):

If you define a variable inside a block (`if`, `while`, `for`, etc...) it's only known inside that block. If you want to use it outside of it/them too, you need to define before the correspondent blocks.

In this case, you can't define inside `if` because it is not known you `return(numofe>0 && numofe<4`. You need to define it before `if` and `for`.

You also need to initialise it first, because it may be returned without being, so: `int numofe = 0;`

Comment: But then the IF part won't know what the variable is.

Comment: That it is not true. The variable will be known for the rest of the function that is right below.